# do drawables need to be recycled?

Tags: android, memory, bitmap, android-drawable

In my activity I have

```
final ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myimage);

img.setImageDrawable(getdrawable()); //getdrawable() is my own function which returns a drawable
```

Then this line

```
img.setImageDrawable(getdrawable()); //this line is
```

is called many times to replace the drawable on the current imageview.

Will I need to recycle the drawable or will the GC do it for me?  and if i do need to recycle then how do i do it?

Comment: I will leave this task to GC

Answer (score 0):

Drawables, like anything else that uses memory, get marked for garbage collection whenever there are no longer any references pointing to them.  If you're running into a situation where memory isn't released as soon as you drop the reference to the previous drawable, well, that's GarbageCollector for you.  GC will try to do its work in the most efficient way possible, which means that, from your perspective, it gets to it when it gets to it, and you can't make it go any faster, even if you call the object's dispose() method.

Read this [guide](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html) for a really good explanation of what's going on under the covers with garbage collection.

Comment: There is a long lived bug in Android that native allocations like a Bitmap's pixel buffer are not counted as allocation when the garbage collector checks the memory usage. It will end up Bitmaps will block the GC triggered by low memory. That's why we have to recycle bitmaps manually. (Actually triggering GC manually helps, too.) At least before ICS (or maybe before JB).